# Finding the first value greater than x in dynamic arrays for Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As shown on Table 1, I have a list of tenors and on Table 2 there is a list of cashflow times.

I would like to make a fully dynamic sheet and are using "#" referencing.
(1) the first tenor that is greater than the cashflow time column (as shown on result 2)
(2) the last value that is smaller than the cashflow time column (as shown on result 1).

Table 1

| tenor |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 0.25 |
| 0.5 |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

Table 2

| cashflow time | result1 | result2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -0.7392 | n/a | 0 |
| 0.1697 | 0 | 0.25 |
| 0.4216 | 0.25 | 0.5 |
| 0.6735 | 0.5 | 1 |
| 0.9253 | 0.5 | 1 |
| 1.1690 | 1 | 2 |
| 1.4209 | 1 | 2 |

Comment: Can you include why you got these results and your own attempt at solving the issue?

Comment: Looking at table 2 the results do not seem to match the description. Can you review or further explain the logic?

Comment: @P.b apologies, i just updated the table to match the description. you can say i'm looking for the two numbers that "cashflow time" is between in the "tenor" table.

Answer (score 1):

For **result1**:

```
=XLOOKUP(C2:C8,A2:A9,A2:A9,,-1)
```

For **result2**:

```
=XLOOKUP(C2:C8,A2:A9,A2:A9,,1)
```

where `C2:C8` are the **cashflow time** values nd `A2:A9` are the **tenor** values.